# Dynamic array of interfaces in SV

Tags: system-verilog

In SV LRM 2012 they are saying that

> interface_instantiation ::=
>   interface_identifier [ parameter_value_assignment ]
>   hierarchical_instance { , hierarchical_instance } ;

When searching meaning of *hierarchical_instance* you can find

> hierarchical_instance ::= name_of_instance ( [
>   list_of_port_connections ] ) name_of_instance ::= instance_identifier
>   **{ unpacked_dimension }**

Finally, it can found that

> unpacked_dimension ::= **[ constant_range ] | [ constant_expression ]**

I would like to read it so that you cannot have dynamic array of interfaces in your SV code, right? But when simulating the following code line both with VCS and Questa, it works without any warning/error:

```
virtual protocol_if ifs[];
```

Why it works? Could you clarify it to me?

Comment: It is since you are using **virtual** interface which is a **pointer/handle to the actual interface**. It might not work if you use actual interface instantiation. When using actual interface, it might give this error: `Variable sized dimension used in module instance array. Please use fixed dimensions in module instance array.`.

Comment: I can do the same kind of interpretation. Anyway, I would like to find an exact explanation in LRM. Probably I cannot find it, but instead, I need to read between lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between declaring an array of instances, and declaring a variable that has an array dimension.

The BNF syntax you show is for `interface_instantiation`, which has similar rules for `module_instantiation`. That is just a shortcut for a generate-for loop which creates multiple instances with instance names that resemble an array index. It's not a true array where each element is an identical copy. Constructs such as `defparam`, `bind`, and others can change the characteristics of each instance, which is why you are not allowed to use a variable to procedurally select a specific instance.

The variable declaration you show is for a virtual interface, which is a data type.

// from A.2.1.3

> data_declaration10 ::= 
>   [ const ] [ var ] [ lifetime ]
>   data_type_or_implicit list_of_variable_decl_assignments ; | ...

// from A.2.2.1 ...

> data_type ::=  | virtual [ interface ]
>   interface_identifier [ parameter_value_assignment ] [ .
>   modport_identifier ]